# Structuring my MySQL search query for use with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm attempting to write a parameterized query with PDO that accepts a number of inputs and acts as a search on a specific table.

There are a number of columns I wish to search on but each of which could be optional. The query simplified might look like:

```
SELECT * FROM item 
WHERE name LIKE '%?%'
AND col2 IN (?, ?, .......)
AND col3 IN (?, ?, .......)
...
```

and with the IN clause, there could be any number (0 or more) of terms for each column.

Since the IN clause won't work with 0 values, and in PDO I'd have to iterate over each array passed in for each IN clause - I'm wondering if there's a better way to structure this as it seems like a big mess.

Comment: So what doe your PHP code look like?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I'm trying to write it atm - it's messy conditionally building '?' into the query for each array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "call_user_func_array" to make it dynamic. This is what I use:

```
public function selectMSData($handlename, $sql, $type='', $params = array())
{
if ( ! is_string($sql) || ! is_array($params) ) {
  die('wrong param types');
}

$this->dbconnect($handlename); //connect to db and save connection with handle-name
$result = array();
$aRows = 0;
if(sizeof($params)==0) {
  //simple query without runtime parameters
  $msres = $this->dbhandle[$handlename]->query($sql);
  if($msres === false) {
    //log error
  } else {
    while($mres = $msres->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      $aRows++;
      $result[] = $mres;
    }
  }
} else {
  //prepared statement using runtime parameters
  $stmt = $this->dbhandle[$handlename]->prepare($sql);
  if(!$stmt) {
    //log error
  }
  $valArr = array();
  $valArr[] = $type;
  foreach($params as $pkey => $pval) {
    $valArr[] = &$params[$pkey];
  }
  call_user_func_array(array(&$stmt, 'bind_param'), $valArr);

  if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    //log error
  };
  $stmt->store_result(); //fetch is super-slow for text-fields if you don't buffer the result!!

  $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
  while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
    $resfields[] = &$row[$field->name];
  }

  call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $resfields);

  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        foreach($row as $key => $val) {
            $c[$key] = $val;
        }
        $result[] = $c;
        $aRows++;
  }
  $stmt->close();
}
$this->result = $result;
return $aRows;
}
```

and you call it like this:

```
$db->selectMSData('my_db_name', 'SELECT * FROM example WHERE a=? AND b=? LIMIT 1', 'ss', array($a, $b));
```